# Sed delete lines with more than one word, excluding a search term

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I'm currently trying to write a sed command that will search a file, and delete lines in the file that have more than one word. However, I need it to exclude deleting a line that starts with a particular symbol (going with "[")

This is what I have so far (this is not including the code to exclude a line, just to delete the lines with more than one word):

```
sed -E '/^\s*\S+\s*$/!d' $1
```

I wanted to go with something like this to exclude searching lines that start with a left bracket ("["):

```
sed -E '/a/!d/^\s*\S+\s*$/!d' $1
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: extra characters after command
```

I'm sure it's something small and ridiculous I'm missing. Is anyone able to help out with this? Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `awk` command will be simpler:

```
awk 'NF<2 || /(^| )\[/' file
```

This `awk` will only print lines that have less than two words or a word starting with `[`

Comment: Does the job perfectly! Should definitely look into awk more. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Through sed,

```
sed -n '/^ *[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+\|^ *\[/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with your command, but following will do the trick :

```
sed -E '/^\s*\S+\s*$|^\[/!d' $1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^[^[]\S*\s\+\S/d' file
```

Delete lines that don't start with `[` and are more than one word.